# Is there a way to include a string in an iOS binary using the linker

Tags: ios, linker

In Go I've used this technique—which used ldflags—to embed the git sha into a binary.¹

Is there some way to do the same with iOS swift binaries?

I'm aware of the answers to this question which involve Info.plist and pre compile shell scripts.  They are fine, but they also always leave a modified Info.plist file in my workspace.

1: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-ldflags-to-set-version-information-for-go-applications

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the --identifer argument to `codesign(1)` is what you are looking for.  From the command-line:

`pushd $PROJECT_HOME; $( xcrun -f xcodebuild) build OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--identifier $( git log -1 --pretty=%H)"`

Display the identifer via:
`codesign -d -r- /path/to/binary`

See Also:
[Codesigning in-depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html)
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html

Comment: That's really interesting, but it's not quite what I'm after. I was hoping to be able to set the value of an arbitrary variable in the application.